# How to get access to html 5 audio volume property in ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, html, ionic-framework

I have an issue with volume under ios devices. For playing music I am using HTML 5 audio. I have a function:

```
setVolume(volume: number) {
  this.audio.volume = volume;
}
```

volume - it is a number in range 0.1-1
that works for android but not for ios, how to fix that issue?

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 5.0.4 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
ios-deploy        : 1.9.4 
Node              : v6.11.3
npm               : 3.10.10 
OS                : macOS
Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: Maybe is an iOs problem: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/audio-volume-levels/153868/3

Comment: Unfortunately, This plugin uses private AVSystemController.h APIs and can't be used for AppStore apps.

Comment: I have found this
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html
On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1